# Question on improper integral using complex integration

Tags: complex-analysis

I tried to evaluate the integral:

> $$\int_0^\infty\frac{1-e^{-x}}{x^{3/2}}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

Using complex contour integral, taking the usual half of an annulus contour in the complex plane but I ran into the difficulty of having an integral from negative infinity to zero which seems unable to consolidate into the integral from zero to positive infinity.
Any help on the detail working steps would be much appreciated.

Comment: Integrating by part
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{1-e^{-x}}{x^{3/2}}\,\mathrm{d}x=-\frac12\frac{1-e^{-x}}{\sqrt x}\bigg|_0^\infty+\frac12\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt x}dx$$

Comment: Integration by parts was also my first thought. If you *require* this to be solved via contour integral, please say this in the question.

Comment: Integration by parts was also my first thought, but i did not work out in detail as in my mind some kind of stuck at the second integral. Now I see. But just out of curiosity, if we use contour integral, how should it be done ? Thank you.